# Почему в dle 14 значения PHP скрипта не записывается в переменную например: [Browsername]?

Tags: php, шаблоны, скрипт, dle

Есть php скрипт, он определяет название браузера и выводит значения через "$browser". Необходимо значения записать в переменную [Browsername].
Вставил данный код скрипта в модуль "show.full.php", в шаблон "fullstory.tpl" прописал переменную {Browsername}, она выводит только "$browser".
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться?

Сам скрипт:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
if (strpos($user_agent, "Firefox") !== false) $browser = "Firefox";
elseif (strpos($user_agent, "Opera") !== false) $browser = "Opera";
elseif (strpos($user_agent, "Chrome") !== false) $browser = "Chrome";
elseif (strpos($user_agent, "MSIE") !== false) $browser = "Internet Explorer";
else $browser = "Неизвестный";
$tpl->load_template("fullstory.tpl");
$tpl->set('{Browsername}', '$browser');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А где вы записали переменную? Вы записали строку...
Так должно быть:

```
$tpl->set('{Browsername}', $browser);
```

Comment: А как правильно, я в PHP не силен....

Comment: @Anitub.ru Я дал строку, в которой была ошибка. Остальное всё верно в плане логики.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, работает!